# Lighting 2D Objects from behind

Tags: opengl, shader, sprite, unity-game-engine, lighting

I am working on a 2.5D lighting problem. I wanted to create an effect where the moon was lighting 2D things from behind. Have you ever seen a solution to a problem like this? I'm trying to use normal maps on a sprite in Unity, which looks fine-ish when the moon is poking out from behind something -- but when it's completely behind it (as in the third picture), the effect doesn't work -- because to light a 2D element in 3D, you have to light it from the front, so far as I know Perhaps there's a solution that doesn't involve real light, but only shaders which reveal an angle-based mask. Do you have any bright (HAW!) ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image: bad]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with using 2D objects so I'm guess your going to have simulate an effect using transparency and looking for some function to calculate the brightness  from an origin (the center of the moon) or (not sure if this is possible) but maybe create a 3d overlay (or backlay if you will) that uses a material that will give you your desired look.....set a transparency on the 2d object to allow the light effects of the 3d rectangle to shine though..

there are probably much beter solutions, I'm just throwing ideas around

Comment: These are some good ideas -- I think if there's some way to completely block the light in front of the objects in a gradient, that would solve part of the problem -- stop the light from going through the middle -- but it would be a flawed effect, since the edges wouldn't bleed light correctly, and the edges would still appear lit when the moon was behind the object, if you catch my meaning.